# How to get to specific items in a list in a model in razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, slider

In a view in Razor I'm passing a model which contains a list ('usageList') of objects that have a Name and UseDescription property.

In JQuery I've made a slider and i want the specific UseDescription to appear when I change the slider value.

The problem is getting the specific object in the list inside the model.
I've got this code (JQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({
            min:1,
            max:3,
            value:1,
            range:"min",
            change: function(event,ui){
                var number = ui.value;
                alert("@Model.UsageList[ui.value].UseDescription");

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

it is not possible to get ui.value in this line:

```
alert("@Model.UsageList[ui.value].UseDescription");
```

If I pass in a number (1 for expample) instead of ui.value things work fine. But I need to get the specific listobject.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: What is the list held in? A grid?

Comment: it's only located in the model passed from the controller

Comment: The model is only available on the server end...not client side.

Comment: add the use description already to the right slides, after that u can reach it easily by using the .attr selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download your list to the client side using javascript. Then, you can get an item by index. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var usageList = []
            @foreach (var item in Model.UsageList)
            {
                <text>usageList.push('@item.UseDescription');</text>
            }

            }
            $("#slider").slider({
                min:1,
                max:3,
                value:1,
                range:"min",
                change: function(event,ui){
                    var number = ui.value;
                    alert(usageList[ui.value - 1]);

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Or use a Json Serializer...this will fail if the value of UseDescription contains a single quote.

Comment: usageList isn't recognized within the foreach loop.

Comment: You are right. I just updated it. Be careful with single quotes as mentioned here.

Comment: That did it! I'll be carefull with the single quotes. Both thanx for the help.